# How parse words with brackets using Python Pyparsing?

Tags: python, pyparsing

I've tried to find free text query inside of user queries.

Let me give an example. User enters:

```
domain:example.com and Welcome to my website
```

Currently the output will be:

```
>> parser.parseString("domain:example.com and Welcome to my website")
([(['domain', ':', 'example.com'], {}), 'and Welcome to my website'], {})
```

My `pyparsing` code is:

```
word = pp.Word(pp.printables, excludeChars=":")
non_tag = word + ~pp.FollowedBy(":")
# tagged value is two words with a ":"
tag = pp.Group(word + ":" + word)
# one or more non-tag words - use originalTextFor to get back
# a single string, including intervening white space
phrase = pp.originalTextFor(non_tag[1, ...])
parser = (phrase | tag)[...]
free_text_search_res = parser.parseString(filters)
```

This is fine and works as expected. What I'm having issue with is that I need to also parse the below query correctly:

```
>> parser.parseString("domain:example.com and date:[2012-12-12 TO 2014-12-12] and Welcome to my website")
([(['domain', ':', 'example.com'], {}), 'and', (['date', ':', '[2012-12-12'], {}), 'TO 2014-12-12] and Welcome to my website'], {})
```

The `date` part is wrong. I expected to be `['date', ':', '[2012-12-12 TO 2014-12-12]']`. Where I have done wrong?

Comment: You can see in the result that the string you’re imagining will be taken as a date has been split at the first space, which isn’t surprising as your definition of `word` is as a series of consecutive `printable`. If you want to use special syntax to denote a date then your pyparsing definition will have to include that, perhaps, a `date` starts with [ and ends with ] and can follow a :

Comment: @barny in printable, square brackets are also included. Is that what you mean? Or I need to explicitly say start and end of the word. [ word ]

Comment: Space isn’t included in printable - that’s why `word` Splits your text into words, isn’t it?

Comment: @barny yes, but including it makes my parser to not parse correctly. If you have a sample code I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like below

```py
word = pp.Word(pp.printables, excludeChars=":")
word = ("[" + pp.Word(pp.printables+ " ", excludeChars=":[]") + "]") | word
non_tag = word + ~pp.FollowedBy(":")
# tagged value is two words with a ":"
tag = pp.Group(word + ":" + word)
# one or more non-tag words - use originalTextFor to get back
# a single string, including intervening white space
phrase = pp.originalTextFor(non_tag[1, ...])
parser = (phrase | tag)[...]

# free_text_search_res = parser.parseString(filters)
# tag.parseString("date:[2012-12-12 TO 2014-12-12]")

parser.parseString("domain:example.com and date:[2012-12-12 TO 2014-12-12] and Welcome to my website")
```

Will give you the below results

> ([(['domain', ':', 'example.com'], {}), 'and', (['date', ':', '[', '2012-12-12 TO 2014-12-12', ']'], {}), 'and Welcome to my website'], {})